# i want to add two numbers in android studio but when i click on a button my app crashed?

Tags: java, android

[image: check my on click code]

I use two edit fields and get their texts in on lick method of a button, but when i click button my app crashed. please help me to resolve this problem.

I am fresh one here, if I make any mistake in uploading my question ignore it
thanks..!

Comment: It would be a lot more helpful to copy and paste the text as text. Speaking only for myself, I don't care if the pretty colors you see in your IDE match the colors we see on here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

Text Field returns a string, which can be a non-number string.
A try-catch block would help if the method could not parse it into an integer.